# Default values for max.request.size and message.max.bytes seem wrong

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The default value for the Producer setting `max.request.size` is 1048576. This controls the maximum size of a request (to a broker) in bytes.

The default value for the Broker setting `message.max.bytes` is 1000012. This controls the largest (record batch) size allowed (by the Kafka server/broker).

1048576 > 1000012

It seems that the defaults are such that a Producer (with this default value) could happen to produce a message which is larger than a Broker (with this default value) will accept, resulting in `MESSAGE_TOO_LARGE` errors.

Am I misunderstanding these configuration settings? Or are the Kafka defaults really such that it is possible to get `MESSAGE_TOO_LARGE` errors with the default values?

Comment: A request includes a message and other metadata. It's not clear how large the metadata is, but it would explain why the request sizes are larger...

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 - the difference between the above is roughly 50KB. It doesn't seem like there'd be 50KB of metadata... but I don't know. Looking for an authoritative explanation for this design decision.

Comment: http://kafka.apache.org? Under protocol?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not sure what you're asking as far as kafka.apache.org.

Comment: "authoritative explanation for this design decision"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Apache Kafka mailing list, this was recently fixed:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/4154

https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/bd5a1c4d368b9e91398e48400965d30d3045062e